# unable to pass jquery sortable value through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-table

I have two tables and i have make them sortable but the only thing missing is i am not able to pass sortable table value through ajax now.Just a small mistake i am doing somewhere.Here is jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/6/)
Here is my code:
dashboard.php

```
<pre>
    <div id="info"></div>
    </pre>  
    <div id="widget_update">
    <div id="Fahrzeuge" /><img src="/admin/images/arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" />
        <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="fahrzeuge">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="NEWS" /><img src="/admin/images/arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" />
        <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="news">          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

dashboard.js

```
$("#widget_update").sortable({
      handle : '.handle',
      update : function () {
          var widget = $('#widget_update').sortable('serialize');         
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {'aktion' : 'show-widget','widget':widget},
        success: function(data){
            $('#widget').html(data.html);
            //location.reload();    
            //showwidget();                 
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Cant delete all widget!!!! Press cancel to go back main menu!!!!');
            //location.reload();
        }
        });
      }
});
```

Comment: `The button id is same for both the tables`. Id should be unique in the html document.

Comment: as you can see in js the button id is removewidgetId....i want to make it dynamically so that i dont want to use button everytime for every select box options....

Comment: You need to pass the table id to `getremovewidgt()` as a parameter when you are calling it.

Comment: yes aashray that i tried but dont know how to write or call the table id in javascript..i think i have to usee loop or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve in terms of the function of the buttons, however it is important to note the [jQuery live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated as at jQuery 1.7.